# Coordinates in contour not Accurate/smooth

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a people counter system and i'm getting the coordinate of each blob detected through the following code:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    try: hierarchy = hierarchy[0]
    except: hierarchy = []
    for contour, hier in zip(contours, hierarchy):
      (x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contour)
      center = (int(x),int(y))
      radius = int(radius)
      if radius>3:
        cv2.circle(frame,center,1,(0,255,0),-1)
        if x>400 and x<450:
            if (abs(prev_x-x))>25:
              cv2.circle(frame,center,1,(0,255,0),-1)
              j=j+1
              prev_x=x
```

Now the coordinates from the rectangle i'm getting isn't smooth. Moreover the centre of circle i'm getting is'nt stable. Can anyone please suggest a better solution at getting the coordinates of each blob/contour smmothly which is not prone to noise and is stable?Mine is moving too waywardly and the moving of centres arent linear.
 If there's a different algorithm available then please do suggest. Thanks.

Comment: did you try to use the center of gravity of your contour instead of the enclosing circle? post some images to get an idea of how your contours look like in their difference

Comment: Can you share images together with your code?